# How did the Night King know that Arya is attacking?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the climax of the *Game of Thrones* episode "The Long Night", how was the Night King able to sense Arya's attack and grab her neck.

Just before the Night King gets hold of his sword to kill Bran, they both share eye contact with each other and then Bran tilts his head to look behind the Night King. But the Night King doesn't look behind and yet he was able to sense the attack from Arya and grabbed her neck even without looking back.

Is it possible because the Night King's mark was placed on Bran which gave access to Bran's vision or was there any other reason?

Comment: Because he heard her going down the yodel that runs from Winterfell tower's to the sacred woods.

Comment: She kind of rushed into him screaming out loud.

Comment: oh yeah she was yoddling out thinking that Night King is deaf :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## She was screaming.

She made herself very audible as seen here:

And, as seen he did turn around to catch her.

Comment: One of the other white walkers seemed to have noticed her just before as well. If the Night King has any warg-like connection with the other white walkers (he seems to be able to control the wights in some magical manner, so maybe there's something similar between the WWs), it's possible NK saw her through the other white walker.

Answer (score 2):

Not only was she screaming, as @Daeron states, but he also has the ability to sense things supernaturally. He knew Jon was coming from many yards away (behind him), and he seemed to be able to sense when the men around Bran died (although he could have seen it by warging).

In terms of why he didn't turn until she was close, he's cocky. He smiled at Dany before throwing a spear and walked towards Bran instead of running. He ended up getting screwed because he didn't expect the knife trick, but he expected her for a while.